# Powershell showing 'ObjectNotFound'

Tags: python, powershell

[image]

I was trying to use 'pyautigui' but with the using 'pip' command but powershell wasn't able to recognise it.
I recieved this message instead:

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install pyautogui
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows `pip` should be added to PATH environment variable. Possible ways to do this:

- While installing, check Add python to Path.
- First find the path of pip.exe, it's usually in Scripts directory of your python installation. Then copy file path and run `setx %PATH% "%PATH%;FULL PATH"` from Cmd.